# How to get the local ip address using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I 'm creating a web app in which i need to save the sessions in the database including the Ip address of the user and the date and time of the session , for that i want to know how to do that ,knowing that the app will be used in LAN .
i 'm using codeIgniter framework.

Comment: @fodilleo use codeigniter input class http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

or

```
echo $this->input->ip_address();
```